# R, dplyr: cumulative version of n_distinct

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I have a dataframe as follows. It is ordered by column `time`.

Input -

```
df = data.frame(time = 1:20,
            grp = sort(rep(1:5,4)),
            var1 = rep(c('A','B'),10)
            )

head(df,10)
   time grp var1
1   1   1    A
2   2   1    B
3   3   1    A
4   4   1    B
5   5   2    A
6   6   2    B
7   7   2    A
8   8   2    B
9   9   3    A
10 10   3    B
```

I want to create another variable `var2` which computes no of distinct `var1` values so far i.e. *until that point in `time`* for each group `grp` . This is a little different from what I'd get if I were to use `n_distinct`.

Expected output -

```
   time grp var1 var2
1   1   1    A    1
2   2   1    B    2
3   3   1    A    2
4   4   1    B    2
5   5   2    A    1
6   6   2    B    2
7   7   2    A    2
8   8   2    B    2
9   9   3    A    1
10 10   3    B    2
```

I want to create a function say `cum_n_distinct` for this and use it as -

```
d_out = df %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(var2 = cum_n_distinct(var1))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming stuff is ordered by `time` already, first define a cumulative distinct function:

```
dist_cum <- function(var)
  sapply(seq_along(var), function(x) length(unique(head(var, x))))
```

Then a base solution that uses `ave` to create groups (note, assumes `var1` is factor), and then applies our function to each group:

```
transform(df, var2=ave(as.integer(var1), grp, FUN=dist_cum))
```

A `data.table` solution, basically doing the same thing:

```
library(data.table)
(data.table(df)[, var2:=dist_cum(var1), by=grp])
```

And `dplyr`, again, same thing:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(var2=dist_cum(var1))
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg, `j` is just the formal name of the typical second argument, so `DT[, x:=1]` can be equivalently written as `DT[j=x:=1]`

Comment: Oh I see, so why not just `data.table(df)[, var2:=dist_cum(var1), by=grp]`? Or `data.table(df)[, var2:=dist_cum(var1), grp]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, no good reason, perhaps that would be better since most people are used to your version; I'll update.

Answer (score 8):

#### A `dplyr` solution inspired from @akrun's answer -

Ths logic is basically to set 1st occurrence of each unique values of `var1` to `1` and rest to `0` for each group `grp` and then apply `cumsum` on it -

```
df = df %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  group_by(grp,var1) %>%
  mutate(var_temp = ifelse(row_number()==1,1,0)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(var2 = cumsum(var_temp)) %>%
  select(-var_temp)

head(df,10)

Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
Groups: grp

   time grp var1 var2
1     1   1    A    1
2     2   1    B    2
3     3   1    A    2
4     4   1    B    2
5     5   2    A    1
6     6   2    B    2
7     7   2    A    2
8     8   2    B    2
9     9   3    A    1
10   10   3    B    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

#### Update

With your new dataset, an approach in base R

```
  df$var2 <-  unlist(lapply(split(df, df$grp),
              function(x) {x$var2 <-0
               indx <- match(unique(x$var1), x$var1)
               x$var2[indx] <- 1
               cumsum(x$var2) }))

  head(df,7)
  #   time grp var1 var2
  # 1    1   1    A    1
  # 2    2   1    B    2
  # 3    3   1    A    2
  # 4    4   1    B    2
  # 5    5   2    A    1
  # 6    6   2    B    2
  # 7    7   2    A    2
```

Comment: Thanks. Pretty nice trick! This works for the example I had mentioned previously, but wouldn't probably work when `var1` is not ordered. I've modified the example to include more general case.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution using data.table that's pretty quick.

## Generic Function

```
cum_n_distinct <- function(x, na.include = TRUE){
  # Given a vector x, returns a corresponding vector y
  # where the ith element of y gives the number of unique
  # elements observed up to and including index i
  # if na.include = TRUE (default) NA is counted as an 
  # additional unique element, otherwise it's essentially ignored

  temp <- data.table(x, idx = seq_along(x))
  firsts <- temp[temp[, .I[1L], by = x]$V1]
  if(na.include == FALSE) firsts <- firsts[!is.na(x)]
  y <- rep(0, times = length(x))
  y[firsts$idx] <- 1
  y <- cumsum(y)

  return(y)
}
```

## Example Use

```
cum_n_distinct(c(5,10,10,15,5))  # 1 2 2 3 3
cum_n_distinct(c(5,NA,10,15,5))  # 1 2 3 4 4
cum_n_distinct(c(5,NA,10,15,5), na.include = FALSE)  # 1 1 2 3 3
```

## Solution To Your Question

```
d_out = df %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(var2 = cum_n_distinct(var1))
```