# r recode by a splitting rule

Tags: r, recode

I have a student dataset including student information, `question` id (5 questions), the `sequence` of each trial to answer the questions. I would like to create a variable to distinguish where exactly student starts reviewing questions after finishing all questions.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(
person =   c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
question = c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,1,2, 1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,4,3,4,4,5,4,5),
sequence = c(1,1,2,1,2,3,1,4,1,2,3, 1,2,3,1,1,1,2,3,1,2,4,2,5,6,3,7,4))

data
   person question sequence
1       1        1        1
2       1        2        1
3       1        2        2
4       1        3        1
5       1        3        2
6       1        3        3
7       1        4        1
8       1        3        4
9       1        5        1
10      1        1        2
11      1        2        3
12      2        1        1
13      2        1        2
14      2        1        3
15      2        2        1
16      2        3        1
17      2        4        1
18      2        4        2
19      2        4        3
20      2        5        1
21      2        5        2
22      2        4        4
23      2        3        2
24      2        4        5
25      2        4        6
26      2        5        3
27      2        4        7
28      2        5        4
```

`sequence` variables record each visit by giving a sequence number. Generally revisits could be before seeing all questions. However, the `attempt` variable should only record after the student sees all 5 questions. With the new variable, I target this dataset.

```
> data
   person question sequence attempt
1       1        1        1 initial
2       1        2        1 initial
3       1        2        2 initial
4       1        3        1 initial
5       1        3        2 initial
6       1        3        3 initial
7       1        4        1 initial
8       1        3        4 initial
9       1        5        1 initial
10      1        1        2  review
11      1        2        3  review
12      2        1        1 initial
13      2        1        2 initial
14      2        1        3 initial
15      2        2        1 initial
16      2        3        1 initial
17      2        4        1 initial
18      2        4        2 initial
19      2        4        3 initial
20      2        5        1 initial
21      2        5        2 initial
22      2        4        4  review
23      2        3        2  review
24      2        4        5  review
25      2        4        6  review
26      2        5        3  review
27      2        4        7  review
28      2        5        4  review
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Could you check your expected output? I think that there is some inconsistency with your request. In row 20, the second student sees the question number 5 (and therefore all the questions). In row 21, the same student revisits the same question; so, I expected the value of your `attempt` in row 21 to be `review` and not `initial`. I am right or did I miss something?

Comment: sorry about a late response, I needed to specify that as well but revisiting the last question is not considered a "review". The student should finish all questions including a second/third/..review but the student must move to another previous question, that is the point where the attempt variable is considered "review". Dis you have a solution? again, apologies for a being late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a challenging question. Took almost 2 hours to find the solution.

Try this

```
library(dplyr)

dist_cum <- function(var)
  sapply(seq_along(var), function(x) length(unique(head(var, x))))

data %>% 
  mutate(var0 = n_distinct(question)) %>%
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(var1 = dist_cum(question),
         var2 = cumsum(c(1, diff(question) != 0))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(var3 = if_else(sequence == 1 | var1 < var0, 0, 1)) %>%
  group_by(person, var2) %>%
  mutate(var4 = min(var3)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(attemp = if_else(var4 == 0, "initial", "review")) %>%
  select(-starts_with("var")) %>%
  as.data.frame
```

Result

```
   person question sequence  attemp
1       1        1        1 initial
2       1        2        1 initial
3       1        2        2 initial
4       1        3        1 initial
5       1        3        2 initial
6       1        3        3 initial
7       1        4        1 initial
8       1        3        4 initial
9       1        5        1 initial
10      1        1        2  review
11      1        2        3  review
12      2        1        1 initial
13      2        1        2 initial
14      2        1        3 initial
15      2        2        1 initial
16      2        3        1 initial
17      2        4        1 initial
18      2        4        2 initial
19      2        4        3 initial
20      2        5        1 initial
21      2        5        2 initial
22      2        4        4  review
23      2        3        2  review
24      2        4        5  review
25      2        4        6  review
26      2        5        3  review
27      2        4        7  review
28      2        5        4  review
```

`dist_cum` is a function to calculate rolling distinct ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25555478/3713478)). `var0`...`var4` are helpers

Comment: your time on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by finding where the reviewing starts (i.e. the next entry after the fifth question has been seen) and where the sequence is 2. See `v1` and `v2`. Then by means of subsetting for every individual person and looping by each subset, you can update the missing entries for the `attempt` variable since it is now known where the reviewing starts.

```
v1 <- c(FALSE, (data$question == 5)[-(nrow(data))])
v2 <- data$sequence == 2
data$attempt <- ifelse(v1 * v2 == 1, "review", NA)
persons <- unique(data$person)

persons.list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(persons))

for(i in 1:length(persons)){      
  person.i <- subset(data, person == persons[i])
  n <- which(person.i$attempt == "review")
  m <- nrow(person.i)
  person.i$attempt[(n+1):m] <- "review" 
  person.i$attempt[which(is.na(person.i$attempt))] <- "initial"

  persons.list[[i]] <- person.i
}

do.call(rbind, persons.list)
   person question sequence attempt
1       1        1        1 initial
2       1        2        1 initial
3       1        2        2 initial
4       1        3        1 initial
5       1        3        2 initial
6       1        3        3 initial
7       1        4        1 initial
8       1        3        4 initial
9       1        5        1 initial
10      1        1        2  review
11      1        2        3  review
12      2        1        1 initial
13      2        1        2 initial
14      2        1        3 initial
15      2        2        1 initial
16      2        3        1 initial
17      2        4        1 initial
18      2        4        2 initial
19      2        4        3 initial
20      2        5        1 initial
21      2        5        2  review
22      2        4        4  review
23      2        3        2  review
24      2        4        5  review
25      2        4        6  review
26      2        5        3  review
27      2        4        7  review
28      2        5        4  review
```

Alternatively, you can also use lapply:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(persons, function(x){
          person.x <- subset(data, person == x)
          n <- which(person.x$attempt == "review")
          m <- nrow(person.x)
          person.x$attempt[(n+1):m] <- "review" 
          person.x$attempt[which(is.na(person.x$attempt))] <- "initial"
          person.x
        }))
```